# Search form controller

Tags: php

I am trying to create a Generic Search form (Controller) object. As in my website I have 4 different search forms, like

at Start Page I have a search form and on List page I have again a search form with more filters and on product page Have a search form with product specific property filters.

And what I want is that when user comes back from product page to list page, all the filters should a selected again automatically and if the user was on page 3 (pagination) the he should land again on page 3. Similarly from list to start, all the selected options should be populated again.

Is there any example available?

Comment: Are you using the core PHP or any specified framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store this information in session variables.

For example, each time a list page is loaded, its number could be added to a `$_SESSION["page_number"];` variable. Then whenever the list page loads again (being navigated from the product page for instance), the session value is used to retrieve the last viewed page. The form filters and other options could be stored in the same manner.